# Help with polar coordinates for physics problem

Tags: physics, polar-coordinates

I need to solve a physics problem but don't know about polar coordinates properly, can anybody help with it?

[image]

Suppose a curve which is a current carrying wire: 
$$r=\frac a{cos\theta(1+\sin^2\theta)}$$

Now magnetic field due an diffrential element of wire at origin is:
$$dB=k\frac{dl\sin\phi}{r^2}\text{ where }k=\frac{\mu_0i}{4\pi}\text{ which is a constant and }\phi\\\text{ the angle between the tangent at that point and the radius vector of that point}$$

Now I convert the equation as:
$$rcos\theta=\frac{r^2}{a(r^2+r^2\sin^2\theta)}\implies x=\frac{x^2+y^2}{a(x^2+2y^2)}$$
and I find $\frac{dy}{dx}=tan\phi$

Now put $dl=rd\theta$ and find:
$$B=\int dB$$

But it is long and **practically unsolvable method**, I also don't know tangents in polar coordinates.Can somebody tell a good way I must use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Biot-Savart's law, magnetic field due to a small element is:
$$dB=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{i\vec{dl}\times \hat{r}}{r^2}$$
Notice that in polar coordinates, $\vec{dl}=dr\hat{r}+r\,d\theta \hat{\theta}$ i.e 
$$\vec{dl}\times \hat{r}=-r\,d\theta \hat{z}$$
where $\hat{z}$ is the direction pointing out of the plane.
$$\Rightarrow \vec{B}=\frac{\mu_0 i}{4\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{-r\,d\theta}{r^2}\,\hat{z}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow \left|\vec{B}\right| &=\frac{\mu_0 i}{4\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{r}=\frac{\mu_0 i}{4a\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos\theta(1+\sin^2\theta)\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{\mu_0 i}{4a\pi}\int_{-1}^1 (1+t^2)\,dt\,\,\,\,(\sin\theta=t) \\
&=\boxed{\dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{\mu_0 i}{a\pi}} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: answer: $$\frac{2\mu_0i}{3\pi a}$$

Comment: @Aditya: Oops, I accidentally wrote that factor of 4.

Comment: how $\vec{dl}=dr\hat{r}+r\,d\theta \hat{\theta}$

Comment: I totally agree and understand your result and procedure, but as i mentioned i know a little about polar coordinates; so if you can tell what I asked in the above comment will give me my answer, my first guess is that it is some standard formula, but please give some insight into it.

Comment: @RE60K Yes, it's a mistake: $\vec{dl}=rd\theta\hat{\theta}$. (see for example here: https://msuperl.org/wikis/pcubed/doku.php?id=184_notes:examples:week10_current_ring)